# How to take values from a column in an excel spreadsheet and place each value into a specific place in a new file copied from a template file

Tags: excel, text

I am a geochemistry student writing my thesis and have little experience with programming, but essentially I'd like to do the following.

I have a column of around 10,000 values I have calculated for the concentration of oxygen in a system each millisecond as it is diffused in to a solution. I would like to take these values and generate an input file exactly the same as a template file for each ms and its corresponding oxygen value, with the files being exactly the same other than the oxygen values that will be taken from the spreadsheet. I can then use these to model how the chemistry of the water will evolve at each level of oxygenation. I'm on windows 10 and the modelling program i'm using is phreeqc. What would be the easiest way to do this? It's probably quite simple for a more adept programmer, but unfortunately I lack much experience in this area.

[example input - O2 concentration column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njCBc.png)
[example output, where the highlighted concentration value of "0.01127" was taken from the input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvbip.png)

Comment: In simple, post few sample data then show desired output. And then explain in brief what you trying to do.

Comment: Tip: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: Sorry, I've added some images to make things clearer

Comment: Okay, that shows example input. Now do you have a simple example of the template file, or at least the parts around where the <milliseconds> and <concentration> need to go?

Comment: Okay, it looks to me like that is the example file for milliseconds = 1, O2 concentration = 0.01127. It seems fairly clear where the O2 concentration needs to go, but which of the '1's need to be replaced with the number of milliseconds? All of the ones after the headings (SOLUTION 1, etc.)?

Comment: Also, is the "10" after the 0.01127 going to stay as 10 for all the other values?

Comment: I need a new file for each concentration, so the number of ms would be in the file name ideally :). The files would be identical besides the O2 values. Yes the 10 would remain the same

Comment: I've posted an answer, but for future reference it would be good to follow the link @DavidLeal posted, as including details in text rather than images makes it easier for a wider range of people to understand your question and be able to suggest answers. :-)

Answer (score -1):

So, having setup a spreasheet as in your example, I then setup a template file at C:\Data\Working\phreeqc_template.dat. The contents are:

```
SOLUTION 1
    temp    12.4
    pH      7.7
    <snip>
    
REACTION 1
    O2(g)   <concentration> 10
#    0.01 moles in 10 steps


end
```

Then I created a macro in the spreadsheet:

```
Sub export_template()
    ' Setup some constants - these should be checked and changed if necessary for your purposes
    ' if you need more flexibility, these could be variables setup at run-time
    ' or you could call the macro with the cursor on the desired concentration column
    ' and set the variable from the ActiveCell's column number...
    
    ' Column to use for millisecond values (A=1)
    Const millisecond_column = 1
    ' Column to use for O2 concentration values (D=4)
    Const concentration_column = 4
    ' first row containing data, rather than headers
    ' If you want to avoid having a file for milliseconds = 0, then you can set this to 3
    Const initial_data_row = 2
    
    ' filename of your template file
    Const template_file = "c:\Data\Working\phreeqc_template.dat"
    
    ' filename for the output files
    ' - the millisecond values will be inserted between them (e.g. "minteq-1.v4.dat")
    Const output_file_start = "c:\Data\Working\minteq-"
    Const output_file_end = ".v4.dat"
    
    ' tag in the template file to be replaced with the concentration values
    Const concentration_tag = "<concentration>"
    
    ' --- Check and change the values above here ---
        
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim milliseconds As Integer
    Dim concentration As Double
    Dim data_row As Integer
    Dim output_filename As String
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' for each row in the active sheet, we use the milliseconds column to complete the
    ' output filename, and replace <concentration> with the value from the concentration_column
    
    data_row = initial_data_row
    ' looping while there is valid data in your millisecond column
    ' you might choose to use the concentration column instead
    While Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(data_row, millisecond_column))
        milliseconds = ws.Cells(data_row, millisecond_column)
        concentration = ws.Cells(data_row, concentration_column)
        
        output_filename = output_file_start & milliseconds & output_file_end
        Call process_template(concentration, template_file, output_filename, concentration_tag)
        
        data_row = data_row + 1
    Wend
    
    MsgBox "Finished."
    
End Sub

Sub process_template(ByVal concentration As Double, _
                     ByVal template_file As String, _
                     ByVal output_file As String, _
                     ByVal concentration_tag As String)

    ' This subroutine needs to open the template file for reading and create an output file for writing.
    ' It should copy the input to the output until it sees the <concentration> tag, which it will replace
    ' with the concentration value and continue.
    ' -- Based on MS docs
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Const TristatUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
    Dim fs_input, f_input
    Dim fs_output, f_output
    Dim output_line As String
    
    Set fs_input = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set f_input = fs_input.opentextfile(template_file, ForReading, True, TristateFalse)
    Set fs_output = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set f_output = fs_output.opentextfile(output_file, ForWriting, True, TristateFalse)
    
    While Not f_input.atendofstream
        output_line = Replace(f_input.readline, concentration_tag, CStr(concentration))
        f_output.writeline (output_line)
    Wend
    f_input.Close
    f_output.Close
    
End Sub
```

The constants near the start of the macro subroutine export_template() should be checked and changed if appropriate for your system. The first two allow you to specify different columns for the milliseconds and O2 concentration, the third allows you to skip header rows. The fourth shows the location of the template file, the next two build up the location and filename of the output files, and the final constant defines the tag that gets replaced in the template file.

What the macro does is to loop down through your milliseconds column while there is still data, for each row, it takes the milliseconds value and the O2 concentration value and processes the template file into an output file using them.
The processing subroutine creates a file using the milliseconds value in the filename, reads the template file line by line and exports it to the output file, replacing the concentration tag with the concentration value.

Obviously, you would need to fill out the template file with the rest of the data, but this should give you a good start.